# how to apply navigation in extjs grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I want to load only 25 rows at a time in grid. After clicking next button next 25 rows should be added. Data in grid is in json format and it is from servlet. I am getting json data from servlet. But i want to load particular part only.  How can implement please help me.

```
    Ext.require([
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.grid.*'
     ]);

    Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.define('Book',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
             'sno',
            'name', 'salary'
        ]
    });

    // create the Data Store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Book',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            // load using HTTP
            type: 'ajax',
            //url: 'http://localhost:8080/sampleweb/AccessServlet',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/sampleweb/DataServlet',
            // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root:'jsonObj'
            }
        }
    });

       var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing');
       var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
    });
    // create the grid
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {text: "sno",width:140, dataIndex: 'sno', sortable: true
            ,editor: {
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                allowBlank: false,
                minValue: 1,
                maxValue: 150000
            }},
            {text: "name", width: 180, dataIndex: 'name', sortable: true,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                typeAhead: true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                selectOnTab: true,
                store: [
                    ['Shade','Shade'],
                    ['Mostly Shady','Mostly Shady'],
                    ['Sun or Shade','Sun or Shade'],
                    ['Mostly Sunny','Mostly Sunny'],
                    ['Sunny','Sunny']
                ]}},
            {text: "salary", width: 180, dataIndex: 'salary', sortable: true,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                allowBlank: false,
                minValue: 1,
                maxValue: 1000000
            }},
            {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                width: 30,
                sortable: true,
                menuDisabled: true,
                items: [{
                    icon: 'http://etf-prod-projects-1415177589.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/trac/docasu/export/2/trunk/client/extjs/shared/icons/fam/delete.gif',
                    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                       store.removeAt(rowIndex);
                    }
                }]
            }
        ],

        renderTo:'example-grid',
        width: 560,
         plugins: [rowEditing],
        height: 400
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need pagination, take a look at the [example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/paging.html) provided by Sencha. Basically, all you have to do on the front-end is to add and configure one [paging toolbar](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging) and the framework takes care about the rest. The real job is on the server side where your servlet will have to parse `start` and `limit` parameters, include them in queries and return the appropriate data. This is an example of the request generated by ExtJS once you correctly incorporated paging toolbar:

```
{
//your request data
..
start: 0,
limit: 25
}
```

This request will fetch first 25 rows. Of course you can configure the number of rows in your application.

Comment: I am using paging toolbar but my grid is loading all the data at once.

Comment: @sirisha You have to define the same store for both grid and paging toolbar.

Comment: Additionally, check if params `start` and `limit` are present in your request. In case they are not present, it means you haven't configured paging toolbar correct. If they are present, then check if server-side parsed them.

Comment: same store for grid and paging toolbar.

Comment: Check my other comment. Paste the part of code where you use paging toolbar.

Comment: toolbar displaying in grid. but it is not loading data depends on start and limit params. please send me piece of code.

Comment: Please examine my comments carefully: "check if params start and limit are present in your request. In case they are not present, it means you haven't configured paging toolbar correct. If they are present, then check if server-side parsed them". Can you record  your request (with Wireshark or Firebug for example) and see if those params are contained in the request?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add

```
limitParam : 10,
pageParam  :'pageNumber',
```

in the proxy attribute of store. If you want to load a specific page use

```
grid.getStore().currentPage = The Page Number You Want To Load;
```

before loading the store.

Comment: My grid loading all the data. It is not performing paging.